# Python library to calculate product promotions, offers, deal or discount

Tags: python, algorithm, billing, point-of-sale

I am working with someone who is building a bespoke Point of Sales (PoS) / Billing system in Python (primary windows with plan to extend on other Operating systems)

Now, we have reach to a point where we want to provide options for promotions, offers, deal or discount.
Features like buy 2 get 1 free, get 3 for the price of 1, buy 2 and get 20 off from total amount, spend 100 and buy any additional product just for 10. etc.

While brainstorming about the solution, thought came in mind that this is not a new and we don't have to reinvent the wheel.

So, I was wondering if there is any python library available that provides this type of solution.
We spent a couple of days searching about this library using Bing/Google. Unfortunately, couldn't find any python library here.

Hence, decided to post a question here and see if anyone has any pointer about this.

Comment: Such features are highly dependent on the target market, field and end user. It may be mentioned in the manual as part of the function of the application, but it will not be cut out as a library by itself. As you might think, it's a reinvention of the wheel, but it's one of the competitiveness of applications/systems/retailers, etc., so many would be developing it proprietary.

Comment: hmm.. this makes sense. That's the one of the reasons we are developing a bespoke PoS even though there are plenty of PoS available in the market.